# Simple jQuery code won't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

This is my small piece of code for hide-show tabs (like an accordion):

```
$('#multiOpenAccordion h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

It is just a copy-paste from the jQuery site - it works in all broswers (including IE7 & IE8) but not IE9.

this is even not a jQuery-UI - only simple jQuery

Why doesn't it work in IE9? How can this be fixed?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="multiOpenAccordion">


                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4>
                                    My Car Proj
                                    <span>Free</span>
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                    site
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4>
                                    My Car Probsp;
                                    <span>Free</span>
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                    bla bla
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: also could you try if fadeToggle() is working?

Comment: the problem might be that I used <p> inside the header - I am trying to rebuilt it without the <p> and it seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Some unknown reason removing the `<p>` element from the header solved the problem (that occurred only in IE9)

Answer (score 0):

if your next points a href in html, try giving these

```
"href=javascript:void(0)"
```

then delete your return false